# Prevent from Android soft keyboard to push alert dialog up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Do you know any way to prevent the alert dialog from being pushing upward when the keyboard opens (when the user insert text to edit text)?

If think I have tried every posible setting for `android:windowSoftInputMode` but it keep happaning.